# When we use a thread, will it work as a parallel process or a serial process in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When we use a thread, will it work as a parallel process or a serial process in C#?

Comment: Please define: what is a parallel or serial process? A thread is well defined in the windows system.

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple processors or cores, most probably they will run in parallel. Otherwise, they run in `pseudo-parallel`, which means they will run sequentially but nondeterministically.

Comment: Could you write in simple English?

Answer (score 1):

When you need to call 2 or more WebServices or Queries form an ASP.NET page request, you  can (should) use Threads to execute them in parallel. The total time taken will be that of the longest action and not the sum of all tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this as an asp.net question, so I believe you need to provide a little more info on what you are trying to do. In ASP.NET, every request is handled on a separate thread, so it is already multi threaded. You should only create your own threads if there is a genuine need to perform long running tasks in parallel. Multi-threading is more commonly used in winforms apps to ensure that the GUI is still responsive to the user while calculations are being run or data retrieved/sent etc.

That said, there are certainly times when you might use new threads in ASP.NET, so please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using threads in your code then those threads will be assigned processing time by the operating system.

If your system has only one processor then each thread will be allocated processing time in small amounts (this is where "critical section" comes in as it will prevent the pausing of a thread within that section by the OS).

If your system has more than one processor then each thread can be run on a separate processor. In theory if the system has one processor per thread then they would execute in a time frame equal to the longest thread. In practice this is not the case as there usually many threads running on a given system.